# invalid refernce to variable c sys refcursor

Tags: plsql

```
DECLARE
   c        SYS_REFCURSOR;
   lv_emp   emp%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN c FOR SELECT employee_id FROM emp;

   --fetch c into lv_emp;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (c.emloyee_id);
END;
```

> ERROR at line 7:
>   ORA-06550: line 7, column 24:
>   PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'C'
>   ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
>   Statement ignored

Comment: The `fetch` you commented out is needed to retrieve a value into a string that `dbms_output` can process. It can’t do anything with a ref cursor, and in any case the cursor doesn’t have any `employee_id` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to list all the employee_id, you could do with `REFCURSOR` as cited below in an anonymous block.

```
VARIABLE c REFCURSOR

DECLARE
BEGIN
   OPEN :c FOR SELECT empno FROM scott.emp;
END;
/
PRINT c;
```

SYS_REFCURSOR in an anonymous block

```
DECLARE
   c_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;    
   l_row      scott.emp%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN c_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM scott.emp;

   LOOP
      FETCH c_cursor INTO l_row;

      EXIT WHEN c_cursor%NOTFOUND;    
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_row.empno || ' : ' || l_row.ename);
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE c_cursor;
END;
/
```

Using SYS_REFCURSOR in a Procedure

**Procedure Creation**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc_cursor (c OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN c FOR SELECT empno FROM scott.emp;
END test_proc_cursor;
/
```

**Execution of the above procedure**

```
DECLARE
   cur       SYS_REFCURSOR;
   p_empno   VARCHAR2 (50);
BEGIN
   test_proc_cursor (c => cur);

   LOOP
      FETCH cur INTO p_empno;

      EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('empno  -->' || p_empno);
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE cur;
END;
/
```